# Как создать свои кнопки управления окнами с помощью QT Designer C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, desktop

как сделать свой дизайн кнопок управления окном с помощью QT Designer C++, как реализовано на примере Telegram Desktop? [image: Кнопки управления окном в Telegram Desktop]

Дело в том, что не очень нравятся стандартные кнопки управления окном в Windows и Linux [image: Кнопки управления окном в Linux Ubuntu] и хотелось бы сделать свои кнопки.

Буду благодарен за ответ. Если уже есть такой же вопрос, на который дан ответ, то скиньте пожалуйста на него ссылку.

Comment: ответ очевиден: нарисовать.

Comment: Вам нужно убрать у окна заголовок, который рисует ось, добавить кнопки управления самостоятельно и реализовать перемещение окна каким-то образом. Первые два пункта несложные, последний я на практике никогда не делал, поэтому подсказать не смогу. Вариант для QML можно посмотреть тут https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations